# How to write integration tests for MongoDb TTL Indexes

Tags: mongodb, groovy, integration-testing, spock, ttl

I would like to ask how to properly write integration tests for MongoDb TTL Index in Groovy and Spock for Kotlin + Spring Boot application. Does Groovy / Spock supports a kind of virtual time for such TTL tests? Waits / sleeps looks like undesirable antipattern. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Why do you want to test this?  Doesn't Mongo test this themselves?

Comment: I would like to test my application endpoint which receives document id and timestamp as query parameters, then sets this timestamp to document expireAt field (MongoDb TTL Index). Finally tests should check if that endpoint works properly for combination of document ids and timestamps.